# INNER And OUTER JOIN On Multiple Nullable Columns

Tags: sql-server

The query we are currently testing gives doubtable results, where `Inner JOIN + LEFT OUTER JOIN != B Count`.

The comparaison columns used in both tables are Nullable, but our goal is clear:

> In case of INNER JOIN or intersection, Nulls should not be used for comparaison.
> In case of LEFT OUTER JOIN, if both Bs are Nulls, should be included as not found in A, otherwise, we should compaire only the Not-Nulls.

**Intesection**

```
SELECT b.c1,b.c2
FROM B as b
Inner JOIN A as a
ON (( b.c1= a.c1 and not a.c1 is null)
  OR (b.c2=a.c2 and not a.c2 is null))
```

The previous code gives duplicate values when one of the columns is null!

**In B not in A**

```
SELECT b.c1,b.c2
FROM B as b
LEFT OUTER JOIN A as a
ON (( b.c1= a.c1 and not a.c1 is null)
      OR (b.c2=a.c2 and not a.c2 is null))
WHERE a.id IS NULL
-- filter duplicates
GROUP BY b.c1,b.c2
```

I guess the problem lies in the `ON` part where we join tables.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Joining on nullable columns seems inherently wrong. How can you index the joining columns?

Comment: Checking if `a.c1` and `a.c2` isn't `NULL` in the `ON` is pointless. If `a.c1` has a `NULL` value then `b.c1= a.c1` can *never* be true (even if it has the value `NULL`, as `NULL = NULL` = UNKNOWN). You might as well write that `ON` as `b.c1 = a.c1 OR b.c2 = a.c2`.

Comment: @Kendle Can we avoid Join in this case and use Where clauses for example?

Comment: @Larnu What is your explanation to duplicate values in the intersection case?

Comment: I'd assume you have a many to many relationship. You've given on [mre] here, so we don't know.

Comment: "In B not in A" should probably use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` check. Sample data and expected results would help to explain your somewhat convoluted logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run this with sub-queries rather than a join if you prefer.

```
SELECT b.c1,b.c2
FROM B as b
WHERE
b.c1 IN (SELECT c1 from a WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL)
OR (b.c2 IN (SELECT c2 from a WHERE c2 IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: You mean OR, this resulted in intersection without repetition, my columns seems to have duplicate values by mistake, thank you.

Comment: This approach could be used in both of queries, so it was helpful